# Why can HTML Geolocation be used in my laptop?

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I am using MacPro Chrome browser. I tried it with GeoLocation, and it really returns my geolocation.

I'm confused. My laptop does not contain GPS, so why can geolocation show my location?

Comment: There is a database that maps IP (range) to location.

Comment: A bit like when you use your phone, you can be geolocalized even though gps is off or even if you dont have gps, because you can be geolocalized with network providers.

Answer (score 1):

From Firefox's "Location Aware Browsing":

> "When you visit a location-aware website, Firefox will ask you if you
>   want to share your location.
>
> If you consent, Firefox gathers information about nearby wireless
>   access points and your computer’s IP address. Then Firefox sends this
>   information to the default geolocation service provider, Google
>   Location Services, to get an estimate of your location. That location
>   estimate is then shared with the requesting website."

For the full document check https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/geolocation/. This is an example of how a browser (in this case Firefox) could handle the geolocation service.

Comment: Interesting; I was not aware there was browser-assist.

Answer (score 0):

And in Chrome 45 geolocation is enabled by default. To change settings look in settings:show advanced settings:content settings:location